# Delete folder in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin App, I'm storing some files in within multiple folders in Internal Storage.

I want to delete it, I can successfully the files, but can't the folder (I want to delete the first/main folder, which contain all the subfolders and files).

Here is my code to delete files, which is working fine. I now wants to delete **.folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/***

```
var list = Directory.GetFiles("/storage/emulated/0/.folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/", "*");

if (list.Length > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        File.Delete(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `Directory.Delete` to delete a folder, not `File.Delete`

Comment: "I want to delete it, I can successfully the files, but can't the folder" why not? What code did you use and what issue did you encounter?

Comment: take 2 minutes to read the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Jason thanks for the doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
   Directory.Delete(list);
```

That should delete the entire path you specified, or add the specific path instead of 'list'

Comment: I would try specifying the path you want to delete specifically rather than the value 'list'. Directory. Delete can be done recursively as well, if you specify the 2nd parameter as true.